# Is it possible to chain strong parameters in a Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I'm currently doing this

```
class DetailsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @detail = Detail.new(params.require(:detail).permit(:user_id, :note))
    if @detail.save
      redirect_to @detail
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  
  def update
    @detail = Detail.find(params[:id])
    if @detail.update(detail_params)
      redirect_to @detail
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  
  private
  def detail_params
    params.require(:detail).permit(:note)
  end  
end
```

Is it possible too chain strong parameters in Rails? I tried doing this but it didn't work

```
class DetailsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @detail = Detail.new(detail_params.permit(:user_id))
    if @detail.save
      redirect_to @detail
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  
  def update
    @detail = Detail.find(params[:id])
    if @detail.update(detail_params)
      redirect_to @detail
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  
  private
  def detail_params
    params.require(:detail).permit(:note)
  end  
end
```

Comment: What are you trying accomplish? Adding user_id only to create?

Comment: yes :) exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To DRY things up I have used the **[tap](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/tap)** method and  done something like this...

```
 def detail_params(is_create = false)
   params.require(:detail).permit(:note).tap do |p|
     p[:user_id] = current_user.id if is_create
   end
 end 

  def create
    @detail = Detail.new(detail_params(true))
    if @detail.save
      redirect_to @detail
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def update
    @detail = Detail.find(params[:id])
    if @detail.update(detail_params)
      redirect_to @detail
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

To just have different sets of parameters, this works...

```
 def detail_params(is_create = false)
   permitted = [:note]
   permitted << :user_id if is_create
   params.require(:detail).permit(permitted)
 end
```

Comment: is it possible to just insert `user_id` as one of the params allowed in the create action (and not set its value to current_user)?

Comment: @vince, sure. don't even need tap for that. Added example to answer.